# Usage of new Class<?>[]{} at getMethod

Tags: java, reflection

Is there any difference between:

```
Method getIDMethod = MyInterface.class.getMethod("getId");
```

and

```
Method getIDMethod = MyInterface.class.getMethod("getId", new Class<?>[]{});
```

MyInterface is as follows:

```
public interface MyInterface {    
    AnotherInterface getId();    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no difference. An empty `Class[]` will be generated implicitly in the first case.

[The Java Language Specification states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1)

> Invocations of a variable arity method may contain more actual
>   argument expressions than formal parameters. All the actual argument
>   expressions that do not correspond to the formal parameters preceding
>   the variable arity parameter will be evaluated and the results stored
>   into an array that will be passed to the method invocation
>   (§15.12.4.2).

and about the [invocation and evaluating arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2)

> If `m` is being invoked with `k ≠ n` actual argument expressions, or, if `m`
>   is being invoked with `k = n` actual argument expressions and the type
>   of the k'th argument expression is not assignment compatible with `T[]`,
>   then the argument list `(e1, ..., en-1, en, ..., ek)` **is evaluated as if
>   it were written as** `(e1, ..., en-1, new |T[]| { en, ..., ek })`, where
>   `|T[]|` denotes the erasure (§4.6) of `T[]`.

Technically, it would be equivalent to

```
new Class[]{} // instead of new Class<?>[]{}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no difference between these two, empty array means method has no parameter

but if your method accept any parameter you must use second form like

```
Method getIDMethod = MyInterface.class.getMethod("setId", new Class<?>[]{String.class});
public interface MyInterface {    
    public void setId(String arg);    
}
```

here is declaration of `getMethod` method in `Class`, as you see second parameter is params array and there is no difference between sending empty array or doesn't send anything

```
public Method getMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)
    throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
// be very careful not to change the stack depth of this
// checkMemberAccess call for security reasons 
// see java.lang.SecurityManager.checkMemberAccess
    checkMemberAccess(Member.PUBLIC, ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader());
    Method method = getMethod0(name, parameterTypes);
    if (method == null) {
        throw new NoSuchMethodException(getName() + "." + name + argumentTypesToString(parameterTypes));
    }
    return method;
}
```